# Wordpress - Get latest custom post from every user

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

how can a get the latest custom post from every user?

```
$args = array(  'post_type'      => 'userdatax', 
                'post_status'    => 'publish', 
                'orderby'        => 'post_date',
                'order'          => 'DESC',    
                'posts_per_page' => 999999 );  

$query_res = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Nice code sample.  Hmmm, doesn't seem to show any effort at actually querying by user.... can you be specific, _every user_?

Comment: have you tried setting posts_per_page to -1?

Comment: Did you want to display the latest post from user wise or current user login?

Answer (score 7):

according to me below code can achieve your goal.

try this code

```
function getUserPosts()
{
    $args = array(
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    ); 
    $users = get_users( $args );

    foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
        // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array(
        'post_type'              => array( 'userdatax' ),
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
        'author'                 => $value->ID,
        'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
        'order'                  => 'DESC',
        'orderby'                => 'date',
        );

        // The Query
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            // do something
            echo the_title();
        }
        } else {
        // no posts found
        }

        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
add_action('init','getUserPosts');
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to display the latest post of each user.`

```js
<?php  
$lastposts = get_posts( array(
  'post_status'    => 'publish', 
  'orderby'        => 'post_date',
  'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );
 
//Code to check only the latest post from  each user is displayed.
if ( $lastposts ) {
 $auther=""; 
    foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
     if($auther!=get_the_author()) { ?>
    <!--Do your html code here -->
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); 
    $auther=get_the_author(); 
   }
  
    endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: i have over 1mio user. I dont think that this code will work :/

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$args = array( 'author' => $user_id, 'post_type' => 'any' );

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

just change posts_per_page to be -1
like that

```
 $args = array(  'post_type'      => 'userdatax', 
            'post_status'    => 'publish', 
            'orderby'        => 'post_date',
            'order'          => 'DESC',    
            'posts_per_page' => -1);  

 $query_res = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: That won't have any effect on the results... -1 means no limit, which is pretty much the same as 999999.